# UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 10752-10753: truncated \uXXXX escape

Tags: python, unicode-escapes

I am getting this error, when i try to read my data

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in
> position 10752-10753: truncated \uXXXX escape

i tryed to put a r before the data to convert it in a raw string but i didnt work.

any advices??

## reading the data

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',100)                                       # extend Columns display lenght to 100 Char
data = pd.read_csv(r'de_full_1.tsv',sep="\t", encoding= "unicode_escape")
data.head(100)
```

the rows in the mentioned are:

10751 GerSenNeg429  negative    Im „Solar Valley“ geht die Sonne unter.
10752 GerSenNeg430  negative    Leere Hallen, tiefe Bunker
10753 GerSenNeg431  negative    Ein paar Topfpflanzen kümmern in der Zentralpforte der Hanwha-Q-Cells AG vor sich hin.
10754 GerSenNeg432  negative    Der Betonbau, der wirkt wie ein verglaster Bunker, ist Endstation für Anfragen.

[picture of rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu2mN.png)

[First rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY7Yf.png)

Comment: What is the text around the mentioned position (10752) in the file?

Comment: My gut feeling is that it is something like `C:\Users\Somebody` which is not an actual unicode escape sequence. If that is the case, then your encoding is wrong, and shouldn't be `unicode_escape` but maybe `utf_8` or something else. (Hard to say without seeing your file.)

Comment: By the way the `r` doesn't do anything here because `'de_full_1.tsv'` is not the string the decoder complains about, it's the data in the TSV file that wrong (or interpreted incorrectly).

Comment: Thanks for adding the text but this is a misunderstanding: It's not about the _row_ 10752, it's about the byte position 10752 - the 10753th byte in the file. But you can also search in your file for `\u` and see what you find, I guess that it is not a unicode escape sequence. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be entirely sure because you are not providing the contents of the file around the mentioned byte position, but I am assuming that the data is just regular text that uses the `\` character freely.

However, using `encoding="unicode_escape"` means that the file is encoding Unicode character with a `\uXXXX` sequence (e.g. `\u03A8` for the character `Ψ`), so if `\u` or `\U` is used in another way not matching a valid Unicode escape sequence (for example the string `C:\Users\Somebody`), you are getting an error.

Your `encoding` should probably a different one. It's hard to say which without seeing your file, but most likely it should be either `utf_8`, `ascii` or `latin_1`.